# momentjs with two separate fromNow() formats

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to get two different types of `relativeTime`.

In one file I have :

```
moment.updateLocale('en', { relativeTime: {
  future: 'in %s',
  past: '%s ago',
  s:  'secs',
  ss: '%ss',
  m:  'a min',
  mm: '%dm',
  h:  '1h',
  hh: '%dh',
  d:  'a day',
  dd: '%dd',
  M:  'month',
  MM: '%dM',
  y:  'year',
  yy: '%dY'
}});
```

with

`moment.utc(date).fromNow()`

But this gets applied globally to all uses of moment, and I want the other uses of moment outside of this files to use the regular longer text formatting for `fromNow()`.

I tried with :

```
let g = moment()
g.updateLocale('en', { relativeTime: {
...
```

But it gives errors `g.updateLocale is not a function`.

Does anyone know how to get two different `relativeTime` settings for the `fromNow()` date formatting?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi do you find any solution for that, I don't find the first answer helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly, this is not necessarily the *most elegant* solution, but in the one file that you use in which you want to use the custom locale format, you can:

1. Save the current (*original default*) format for `relativeTime` to an object.
2. Globally set the locale's `relativeTime` format to your custom format.
3. Perform all of the `moment` date/string operations you need to do.
4. Restore the original default format by globally setting the locale's `relativeTime` format back to the object which you saved.

It would look like this:

```
const CONFIG_ORIG = moment().locale("en").localeData()._relativeTime;
const CONFIG_NEW = {
  future: "in %s",
  past: "%s ago",
  s: "secs",
  ss: "%ss",
  m: "a min",
  mm: "%dm",
  h: "1h",
  hh: "%dh",
  d: "a day",
  dd: "%dd",
  M: "month",
  MM: "%dM",
  y: "year",
  yy: "%dY"
};

const DATE = new Date();

// Original format displays: "a few seconds ago"
const string1 = moment.utc(DATE).fromNow();

moment.updateLocale("en", { relativeTime: CONFIG_NEW });
// Custom format displays: "secs ago"
const string2 = moment.utc(DATE).fromNow();

moment.updateLocale("en", { relativeTime: CONFIG_ORIG });
// Restored original format displays: "a few seconds ago"
const string3 = moment.utc(DATE).fromNow();
```

Here's a Code Sandbox that shows this in action:

[image: Edit momentjs locales]

---

Additional resources:

- [Moment.js Documentation on changing locales locally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/)